# Hive query fails with file not found error that should not be possible

Tags: hive, hql

I have a hive external table that is partitioned by the date and time it was inserted, say for example `20200331_0505` which is in `YYYYMMDD_HHMM` format.

Currently there is only one partition:

```
> hdfs dfs -ls /path/to/external/table    
-rw-r----- 2020-03-31 05:06 /path/to/external/table/_SUCCESS  
drwxr-x--- 2020-03-31 05:06 /path/to/external/table/loaddate=20200331_0505
```

And if I run a hive query to find the partitions:

```
select distinct loaddate from table;  
+----------------+
|    loaddate    |
+----------------+
| 20200331_0505  |
+----------------+
```

That is expected and what I want to see, but if I run this:

`select * from table where loaddate=(select max(loaddate) from table);`
Then I get this error:

```
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 3, vertexId=vertex_1585179445264_14095_4_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1585179445264_14095_4_00 [Map 3] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: <Table> initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1585179445264_14095_4_00 [Map 3], java.lang.RuntimeException: ORC split generation failed with exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://path/to/external/table/loaddate=20200327_0513 does not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1851)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1939)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:524)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:779)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:243)
```

So it is trying to load a partition that does not exist, `20200327_0513`, what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you try running `SHOW PARTITIONS <table>;`?

Comment: I ran that it it showed 6 old partitions that should not be there

Comment: Thats what happens when you delete files from hdfs without keeping Hive metadata in sync. Now, you'll have to clean it up by `ALTER TABLE <table> DROP PARTITION partition_spec` before any query starts working again.

Comment: What is the difference between `ALTER TABLE <table> DROP PARTITION partition_spec` and `msck repair table <table> sync partitions`?

Comment: `SYNC PARTITIONS` will also try to add partitions that are missing. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete partitions either directly with the `rm` command or with something like a `SaveMode.Overwrite` write command, it does not alert hive to the changes in partitions, so you need to tell hive that the partitions have changed. There are many ways to do this, the way I chose to fix it was:

`msck repair table <table> sync partitions`